# How do git server hooks run on git server hosted on windows

Tags: windows, git, server, hook, fileshare

Very new to GIT. This is more an educational question!

Our bare repo is hosted on windows server shared network folder(file:// protocol). We use eGit on our local machines to interact with it.

If we set up a pre-recieve or update hook on the server, how/who will invoke it? Does the client git(eGit) invoke the hook scripts on the server(seems unlikely) OR is there a git daemon on the server that is responsible for running these scripts? if it is the daemon, is there some additional setup to get this running?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> If we set up a pre-recieve or update hook on the server, how/who will invoke it?

Any gut push to that bare repo would trigger the execution of the [server-side `pre-receive` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks): no need for a git daemon or any listener, with the [file ("local") protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol).